# usage of setcontentview in android

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

Please help me for going from `main.xml` to another layout by showing the main layout for 5 seconds with an image.

Only one image is there in main layout.

Comment: Try using a more descriptive title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you are in search of **`"Splash Screen to show in android"`** which is showing image or logo regarding an application for the few seconds.

And for implementing "Splash screen", look at this example: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-loading-welcome-splash-spash-screen-example/ , which i found exact solution.

Comment: @mohammedsuhail: This looks what you are looking for. Remember you don't go from a layout to a layout. You go from an `Activity` to an `Activity`.